# jQuery Mobile popup only works on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a really simple form that displays a single field. When you punch in a value and hit submit, it gives you a list of checkboxes. You check some and then click another button below and it displays a success/failure message.

I'm trying to convert this to a jQuery mobile app but am having nothing but problems. For example, I can pragmatically call a popup using `$("#element").popup("open");` when the page first loads, but after the post when I call the popup open like above I see the URL change but no popup is visible and it's pretty much the exact same page. I also tried just posting the checkboxes to a secondary URL (`/update`) and then use an HTTP redirect back to the original page, but somehow jQuery Mobile is breaking that.

I've pasted the majority of the code below. If anyone can point me in the correct direction, that's all I'm looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
        $(document).on("click", "#button", function(e) {
            // Do ajax stuff here
            $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
        });           
    });     
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="lookup" data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Lookup Order</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">   
    <?php if (validation_errors()): ?>
    <div class="errors"><?=validation_errors()?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('error')): ?>
    <div class="errors"><?=$this->session->flashdata('error')?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <form method="post" id="search_form" action="/search">
    <label for="term">Term:</label>
    <input type="number" data-clear-btn="true" name="term" id="term" value="<?=set_value('term')?>" />  
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>


    <?php if (!empty($fish) && $fish->num_rows()): ?>
    <form method="post" action="/update">
    <br /><strong>Species:</strong> <?=$species?><br />
    <hr />
    <a href="#" class="uncheckall">Uncheck All</a> / <a href="#" class="checkall">Check All</a><br />

    <?php foreach ($fish->result_array() as $k => $f): ?>

        <fieldset data-role="fishgroup">
        <?php if (!$f['is_deleted']): ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fish[]" id="checkbox-<?=$f['id']?>" value="<?=$f['id']?>" checked="checked" />
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="fish[]" id="checkbox-<?=$f['id']?>" value="<?=$f['id']?>" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <label for="checkbox-<?=$f['id']?>">
            <?php if ($f['type']): ?>
            <?= $f['1'] ?> <?= $f['2'] ?> Attr: <?= $f['3'] ?> Attr: <?= $seat['4'] ?>
            <?php else: ?>
            <?= $f['3'] ?> <?= $f['4'] ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </label>
        </fieldset>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <a href="#" class="uncheckall">Uncheck All</a> / <a href="#" class="checkall">Check All</a><br /><br />

    <input type="button" value="Update Fish(s)" id="button" />
    </form> 
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
    </div>  
    </div> <!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end page -->  

</body>
</html>
```

Using the following prevents the click handler from being called twice but I still don't get the actual popup after the initial page load:

```
$(document).off("click").on("click", "#button", function() {
    $(" #popupBasic").popup("open");
});
```

All I'm getting is `#&ui-state=dialog` added to the URL, and calling `$("#button").popup("close");` removes that.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that youre attaching same handler multiple times add

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
    $("#button").off();
    $(document).on("click", "#button", function(e) {
        // Do ajax stuff here
        $("#popupBasic").popup("open");
    });           
});     
</script>
```

Comment: It does look like it's calling it twice but `$("#button").off();` didn't fix anything.

Comment: @JSP Basically you need to add check if handler is added, and remove and add it again. Or prevent it from being added twice, you can get handlers $("#button").data()